# How to write a unit test case for a function which doesn't return any result

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

How to write a test case for a function which doesn't return anything but having some logic / calculation depends on global variable values. I am using jasmine framework to write test cases for JavaScript functions.

```
var a = 10, b = 20, c = 0; //a and b variables holds dynamic values

function add(){  
    c = a + b;
}
```

In above case How to write test case for add() function using jasmine?

Comment: By refactoring the function to not rely on global vars :)

Comment: Depends on what you wanna test, in general you can still catch exception by executing it.

Comment: Maybe if you gave a more realistic example? What purpose does the real function perform?

Answer (score 0):

(Modifying global variables being a bad idea in general and other design issues notwithstanding) you can just call `add()` and see if the `c` is correct afterwards

```
describe("Test global variable modifiers", function() {
  var a, b, c;

  beforeEach(function () {
    a = 10;
    b = 20;
    c = 0;
  });

  it("should add a and b values to c", function() {
    add();

    expect(c).toBe(30);
  });
});
```